EF Core mechanisms in .NET Core to handle concurrency issues
I am just starting to learn about concurrent processing in EF Core to make consistent applications and I have some questions, Microsoft documentation says the following:
using var context = new PersonContext();

// Fetch a person from database and change phone number
var person = context.People.Single(p => p.PersonId == 1);
person.PhoneNumber = "555-555-5555";

// Change the person's name in the database to simulate a concurrency conflict
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
    "UPDATE dbo.People SET FirstName = 'Jane' WHERE PersonId = 1");

var saved = false;

while (!saved)
{
    try
    {
        // Attempt to save changes to the database
        context.SaveChanges();
        saved = true;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.Entity is Person)
            {
                var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
                {
                    var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
                    var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

                    // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
                    // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
                }

                // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
                entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                    + entry.Metadata.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

I have this code of the WeatherService:
public WeatherForecast UpdateMeasurementsForToday()
{
     var saved = false;
     var date = DateTime.Today;
     var specified = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);

     while (!saved)
     {
         try
         {
             var entityFromDb = _source.GetWeatherByDate(specified);
             entityFromDb.TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(30);
             
             _source.UpdateEntity(entityFromDb);
             saved = true;
             return entityFromDb;
         }
         catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
         {
             foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
             {
                 if (entry.Entity is WeatherForecast)
                 {
                     var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                     var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                     if (databaseValues is null)
                         throw new ArgumentException("Сущность была удалена");
                     entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
                     entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     throw new NotSupportedException(
                         "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                         + entry.Metadata.Name);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     throw new ArgumentException();
}

Code from _source repository:
public void UpdateEntity(WeatherForecast newEntity)
{
    var entityFromDb = _ctx.Forecasts.First(c => c.Id.Equals(newEntity.Id));
    entityFromDb.TemperatureC = newEntity.TemperatureC;
    entityFromDb.SummaryUpdates++;
    entityFromDb.Version = Guid.NewGuid();
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
}

And I have a question, why when we get DbConcurrencyException we do some extra steps like in Miscrosoft documentation?
Can't we just go back and ask for NEW data (I tried this way and it really didn't work properly, the loop was endlessly throwing DbConcurrencyUpdateEx, I think it's due to the fact that EF Core caches data).
Another issue is when we may need a situation where we need our proposed values and NEW values from the database to resolve a conflict, because our proposed values are based on the old ones, logically it seems as if we just need to write
entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(databaseValues);

and kind of suggest new values.
But in the documentation we again go through the properties in detail.
Also, probably obvious for an insider, but I genuinely don't understand why my concurrency test is unstable:
public async void UpdateWeather_Updatingsimultaneously_SummaryShouldConsiderUpdateCounters()
{
     var rep1 = new EfWeatherRepository(_ctx1);
     var rep2 = new EfWeatherRepository(efDbInitializer.Ctx);
     var weatherService1 = new WeatherService(rep1, _fakeService.Object);
     var weatherService2 = new WeatherService(rep2, _fakeService.Object);
     var createdEntity = weatherService1.MeasureTodayWeather();
     var task1 = Task.Run(() => weatherService1.UpdateMeasurementsForToday());
     var task2 = Task.Run(() => weatherService2.UpdateMeasurementsForToday());
     await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
     var result = rep1.GetEntityById(createdEntity.Id);
     result.SummaryUpdates.Should().Be(2);
}

I'm intercepting the conflict, updating the data and loading the weather entity into the database with the NEW data, but sometimes the test fails because the number of updates is 1 instead of 2.
Class definition
public class WeatherForecast : IUnique
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int SummaryUpdates { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public Guid Version { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}

Sql table definition (I have only 1 table)
"forecasts" "public"    "Forecasts" "Id"    1       "NO"    "integer"
"forecasts" "public"    "Forecasts" "Date"  2       "NO"    "timestamp with time zone"
"forecasts" "public"    "Forecasts" "SummaryUpdates"    3       "NO"    "integer"
"forecasts" "public"    "Forecasts" "TemperatureC"  4       "NO"    "integer"
"forecasts" "public"    "Forecasts" "Version"   5       "NO"    "uuid"
"forecasts" "public"    "Forecasts" "Summary"   6       "YES"   "text"

I used the code from the MS documentation

Can you show your full SQL table definition, as well as the C# model

@Charlieface, yes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int SummaryUpdates { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public Guid Version { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}


@Charlieface, sry, tried to prettier this one, but it doesnt work in commets and i didnt found how to edit my question to add defition of entity

There is an [edit] button right there. Please show the table definition also, as well as any triggers.

"Can't we just go back and ask for NEW data" - of course we can. You might be forgetting the most vital part of your app though; your user. They just spent minutes (or longer) carefully editing that data; what will you do with their edits? What will you do with the other user's edits (the user that caused the concurrency issue)? Handling the case of two humans slowly editing the same db record isn't always "the last person to press save wins" - think about what you do when there are git merge conflicts - you take yours, take theirs or do a 3 way and blend the two edit sets. That needs a UI

@flackoverstow, But I meant about not showing this new data to the user, just apply it to the new data without notifying him, because in my case, it's not critical data and can be changed again, another thing would be possible if it was a transaction between accounts, well, and I think even here the option of updating the data without notification is suitable, because the person wanted to transfer money for example, what difference does it make if someone transferred money from the account to other transactions, the error takes place if now there are not enough funds in the account.

@Charlieface, im added sql table definitions, im have not triggers in my db

I think it's due to the fact that EF Core caches data no it's because of the optimistic concurrency model used since the late 1990s instead of pessimistic transactions, in VB6, ADO and all .NET versions since. if someone transferred money from the account to other transactions that's the job of a single UPDATE WHERE.. not client-side code. You don't need all that code for optimistic concurrency. You need to understand how it works and why, and decide from a business perspective what the correct action is. Reloading data is only valid if you know what to do with it.

@RiyazVagapov this isn't a .NET peculiarity either. You'd get similar behavior in PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL or SQL Server with Snapshot Isolation enabled. Databases that use multi-version concurrency control allow multiple readers to read data while a writer modifies the same row. Only conflicting updates are blocked

@PanagiotisKanavos, I see what you mean, but my model has a version property and so if we go into the database and see that our version is old, we get an exception and I expect my operation to react like that:
load the new data and go to the update method again (counter balance, etc.)
because this method already takes into account which balance values are allowed.

Then do it; when you get the concurrency exception, indicating that the context has detected its data is stale, fetch the data again, change the data again and save it again - "last person to press save wins". If you don't care for EF to give you a concurrency exception at all, then just fire off an UPDATE query that doesn't heed any existing table data, by whatever means you like so you never get the exception, you just issue a last save that always wins

@flackoverstow, I want the data to be fresh, if I do _entity.Balance-=50;
and I don't see that my data is out of date and someone had time to change it before, so the balance is no longer suitable for withdrawing 50 units, if we don't check the data, the balance will become unusable, so I use application level versioning with concurrencyCheck token, but I don't understand why two half a decade long incrementing does not give result 2, but shows result 1, but it happens in 30% of cases, mostly the result coincides.

@flackoverstow, because logically, when there is an increase by 1, it is a completely different belief and an exception must occur.

Arguably you should probably instead do a direct UDPATE eg await Db.AccountsWhere(a => a.Name == someName && a.Balance >= toDeduct).ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters.SetProperty(a => a.Balance, a => a.Balance - toDeduct)); then check the result of that to see if a row got updated.

Amen. Don't try to do what should be an atomic operation (to two accounts? One is decremented the other is increased? Use a transaction too) as a drag to client, edit, send back.. Use a screwdriver for this screw, not your ma's best carving knife

@RiyazVagapov EF Core natively supports version columns, just like ADO.NET's DataTable and DataTableAdapter did. The ADO.NET  Optimistic Concurrency page has nothing to do with EF Core but describes the same patterns, explains why they exist and how to handle conflicts in the way end users want. You'll notice the two pages are quite similar

@RiyazVagapov I expect my operation to react like that: it doesn't matter what you expect. What do your users expect? Discarding the current changes is as valid as overwriting the stored values or rerunning the operation, or telling users the data has changed, showing them the old and new data and asking them what to do. This isn't about accounts and amounts - which isn't a realistic example anyway. In real applications accounts have business transactions, not stored amounts. Totals are used for convenience and updated periodically in the background

@RiyazVagapov in some application scenarios it may be OK to just persist your own changes, eg if one thread modified the Surname of a customer and another the Preferred Customer flag.
